# Лямбда-выражения применительно к массивам

Tags: массивы, лямбда-выражение, julia

Меня интересует есть ли в `Julia` лямбда-выражения подобные тем, что есть в `Python`? Поясню на примере. Допустим у нас есть список `a = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]`, его нужно привести к виду `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`; в `Python` это можно сделать так: `a = list(map(lambda x: x // 2 + 1, a))`. Объявляю массив целочисленных значений: `a = Int32[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]`, а дальше, если честно, теряюсь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А дальше тот же `map`, только лямбда в Julia - т.н. стрелочная функция:

```
a = Int32[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
a = convert(Array{Int32, 1}, map(x -> floor(x / 2) + 1, a))
```

Без `convert` все тот же `map` вернул бы массив чисел `Int64`. В документации все это описано.